# how to manage the successfully response from a post method in angular 5

Tags: php, angular, typescript, drupal

Okay, I'm stuck with a login. It suppose to send this data with a post method:

**POST URL:**

```
/user/login?_format=json
```

**Header:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

**POST data:**

```
{
  "name": "username",
  "pass": "password"
}
```

**I do all that with the login() function:**

```
login (user: User): Observable<User> {
  // let's make the url 
  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/user/login?_format=json`;  
  // the data comes in the 'user' array
  // the header is define above "Content-Type": "application/json"  
  const loginReturn = this.http.post(url, user, header);          
  return loginReturn 
  .pipe( 
    tap((user: User) => this.log(`Looged user  id=${user.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<User>('login'))
  );
}
```

And it works, but i dont know how to manage this Successful response:

```
{
  "current_user":{
    "uid": "1",
    "roles":[
      "authenticated",
      "administrator"
    ],
    "name": "username"
  },
  "csrf_token":   "asda09820380_2238019280dk09n908asjdlkajdaoa",
  "logout_token": "asdasd09a8sdaslkdasl-asdasdklsajdlkasdjlksj"
}
```

I need to use the **csrf_token** and the **logout_token** for future get methods.

**For log out, use the logout token in a GET request. The ends the user's session.**

```
/user/logout?_format=json&token=asdasd09a8sdaslkdasl-asdasdklsajdlkasdjlksj
```

**GET login status:**

```
/user/login_status?_format=json
```

**GET token:**

```
/rest/session/token
```

I want to know how to use the tokens coming from the post method...

thanks you, and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Store the tokens in localStorage and use them when needed

Comment: how?? any example? @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example

Subscribe to your login method to log the user in from your authentication service

```
//authenticationService.ts 

doLogin()
{
    yourService.login().subscribe(user=>
    {

        //set your own flags to log the user in here and store relevant info
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        localStorage.setItem('currentCSRFToken', user.csrf_token);
    })
}

doLogout()
{
    let logoutToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).logout_token;
    yourService.logout(logoutToken).subscribe(resp=>
    {

        //set your own flags to log the user out here and reset session data
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', null);
        localStorage.setItem('currentCSRFToken', null);
    })
}
```

And add this logout method to the service where you declared the loginmethod

```
//yourService.ts

    logout (logoutToken: string): Observable<any> { //don't know what your logout method returns


    const url = `${this.mainUrl}/user/logout?_format=json&token=${logoutToken}`;
    return this.http.get(url, user);

}
```

Comment: I got a property 'csrf_token' does not exist on type 'Object'. @David

Comment: Change user => to (user :any)=> in the subscribe method, or to (user : User) => if your user class have the correct properties defined